# Integration of Stripe payment Gateway into asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, stripe-payments

I want to integrate Stripe payment gateway in asp.net webforms. I have an aspx page in which I have stored the amount to be charged from the customer into a variable. I want to send this amount value to stripe payment gateway and accordingly receive the status of the payment. Also, I want Stripe to maintain the database of the customers accordingly.

Comment: Check out the demo app and download the code to accept payments and subscriptions with all payment methods with Stripe's newest product, Payment Element --> https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collecting payment details in accordance with [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) requires using [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) for card information on your page. We have a [guide for this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=elements) which included .NET snippets for the server side. You may, however, wish to look at [using Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#add-checkout-button) to manage the payment part of your integration with much less effort.

Comment: While using Checkout as you mentioned, Stripe Checkout does not open. only the same page remains with "?" appended at the end of the same URL .

Comment: What do you mean "does not open"? This might be better as a new question, but if you're following the integration and using `redirectToCheckout` then you'd expect to arrive at the Checkout page.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it! If the answer helped remember to mark it as accepted :)